# Firefox HTML5 video playback inconsistancy

Tags: firefox, loops, html5-video, autoplay

Hey all,
I've got an HTML5 video on a page. When tested locally, Chrome, Safari, and Opera work beautifully. Firefox plays it, but doesn't loop as efficiently as the others. The real problem is when it's tested off a server. Firefox doesn't play the video, but recognizes there is one there. I was wondering if all that open ended three-different-ways syntax can be swung in Firefox's favor.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
    <video id="vid_home" width="780" height="520" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
      <source src="Video/fernando.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <source src="Video/fernando.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support this videos playback.
    </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

take out the closing tag from your source tag, it should work then

Comment: I hope you meant that in the way, that the opening tag should then also have a `/>` at the end.